# How do I replace a string while maintaining the case?

Tags: java

I want to replace a string by removing the s in the end

Example

```
Sticks -> Stick
STiCKs -> STiCK
StICks -> StICK
sticks -> stick
```

while using the

```
string.replace("sticks", "stick");
```

doesn't maintain case as it is case sensitive, so I'm seeking for a better option.

Comment: Show what you have tried. Well to give you an idea just find out lastIndexOf('s') then find out substring for your last "s",then use str.replace("s", "")

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: But the 'Sticks' on the string can be anywhere
Example
"He found some StiCKs"
"Some STiCkS were on the ground"
"Sticks were found on that tree"
many more

Comment: What have you tried please share your code.

Comment: Tried String.replace("sticks", "stick");
I think that StringUtils.Replace("Sticks", "stick"); does the same

Comment: Why are you replacing "sticks" with "stick" just replace last occuring "s" with ""

Comment: I'm grabbing Sticks from a file.
The user can define the messages, don't want to remove the last occuring s without it being sticks.

Comment: Your question don't make sense. When you replace a String with something, the matched portion will be entirely replaced with what you specify, hence there is no such thing as replacement while retaining the case. Instead, are you judt trying to remove the last character?

Comment: I don't really get why all answers so far use regex and `replace`. Just check the last character of the string and use `substring`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a very simple regex for this mission.

`(?i)` guarantees that your regex will be treated case insensitive

[**Demo : `(?i)(stick)s`**](https://regex101.com/r/SwTTCP/1/)

[**Ideone Java Demo**](https://ideone.com/SGFWdR)

```
string.replaceAll("(?i)(stick)s", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is regular expressions:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(stick)s", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE) .matcher(inputString);
while(matcher.find()) {
matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1));
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);
String outputString = sb.toString();
```

Edit: this is more or less what does String::replaceAll, but replaceAll doesn't give a case insensitive option.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to remove the `'s'` at the end of the `String` you can simply use `substring` method like this:

```
String myString = "sTiCks";

myString = myString.substring(0, myString.length()-1);

// Result "sTiCk"
```

If you need to remove a `char` or `String` from your `String` not knowing where this part will be, you can try something this:

```
String myString = "sTiCks";

// Part you want to delete
String stringToDelete = "Ck";

// Find where that part starts inside your String
int index = myString.indexOf(stringToDelete);

// If found, use substring method to take only what is before and after that part
if (index >= 0)
    myString = myString.substring(0, index) + myString.substring(index + stringToDelete.length(), myString.length());

// Result "sTis"
```

This will delete the desired part only the first time it finds it. But if the part you want to delete appears more than once in your `String` you can modify the code to this:

```
String myString = "sTiCks";

// Part you want to delete
String stringToDelete = "s";

int index;

while ((index = myString.indexOf(stringToDelete)) >= 0)
   myString = myString.substring(0, index) + myString.substring(index + stringToDelete.length(), myString.length());

// Result "TiCk"
```

I hope one of these solutions fits your case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why all the answers so far are so complex. You can just check the last character and if it's a `s` (or `S`) you use `String#substring` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int))) and leave out the last character:

```
String text = "STiCks";

char lastCharacter = text.charAt(text.length() - 1);
if (lastCharacter == 'S' || lastCharacter == 's') {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length() - 1);
}
```

---

If you want to apply that method to multiple words, for example in a sentence, tokenize the sentence first. Then apply the method to each word and rebuild the sentence.

```
String sentence = StiCks are nice, I like sticks"
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    joiner.add(removePluralSuffix(word));
}
String result = joiner.toString();
```

or the same with Streams:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(sentence.split(" "))
    .map(this::removePluralSuffix)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
```